# Why won't the link go to controller, Spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am having trouble in redirecting the link of below code to my controller class.

This is the code:

```
 $('#ticketDT').DataTable({
            "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
            "responsive": true,
            "ordering": false,
            "scrollY": "300px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "ajax": "ticketList.json",
            "bDestroy": true,
            "deferRender": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                {"mData": "ticketNumber"},
                {"mData": "category"},
                {"mData": "subcategory"},
                {"mData": "status"},
                {"mData": "requestedBy"},
                {"mData": "ticketNumber",
                    "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        $(nTd).html("<a class='linkColor' href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assignMessageTicket?sender_assign=" + encodeURIComponent(sender) + "&portId_assign="+portId+"&messageId=" + encodeURIComponent(messageId) + "&ticketNumber_assign=" + encodeURIComponent(oData.ticketNumber) + "'><span data-toggle='tooltip' title='Assign'><i class='ti-plus btn btn-simple btn-assign btn-icon' data-mode='assignTicket'></i></span></a>");
                    }
                }
            ],
```

This is my handler for the controller class:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = {"assignMessageTicket"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('CWO_ENCODER,ADMIN')")
public ModelAndView assignMessageTicket(@RequestParam(value = "sender_assign",required = true) String sender,
        @RequestParam(value = "portId_assign",required = true) String portId,@RequestParam(value = "messageId",required = true) String messageId,
        @RequestParam(value = "ticketNumber_assign",required = true) String ticketNumber,
        ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String currentUser = request.getRemoteUser();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
    Date date = new Date();
    String currentDate = formatter.format(date);
    dashboardService.assignMessageSmsMessages(messageId,ticketNumber);
    dashboardService.assignMessageSmsReply(messageId,ticketNumber);
    dashboardService.addRecentlyAssignedMessage(sender,portId,ticketNumber,currentUser,currentDate);
    String newSender = URLEncoder.encode(sender, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%2B");
    String newPortId = URLEncoder.encode(portId, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%2B");
    boolean hasError = false;
    model.clear();

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:conversation?sender="+newSender+"&portId="+newPortId+"&hasError="+hasError); 
}
```

This is my updated code.

The link to the controller is

```
$(nTd).html("<a class='linkColor' href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assignSpecificMessage?messageId="+messageId+"&sender_assign=" + encodeURIComponent(sender) + "&portId_assign="+portId+"&ticketNumber_assign=" + encodeURIComponent(oData.ticketNumber) + "'><span data-toggle='tooltip' title='Assign'><i class='ti-plus btn btn-simple btn-assign btn-icon' data-mode='assignMessageTicket'></i></span></a>");
```

The controller is

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"assignSpecificMessage"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('CWO_ENCODER,ADMIN')")
public String assignSpecific(@RequestParam(value = "sender_assign",required = true) String sender,
        @RequestParam(value = "portId_assign",required = true) String portId,@RequestParam(value = "messageId",required = true) String messageId,
        @RequestParam(value = "ticketNumber_assign",required = true) String ticketNumber,
        ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) {


    return "conversation";
}
```

I tried to create a new handler to test it, Still, The same error appears.

Comment: can you inspect in browser, if there are any errors.

Comment: @secretsuperstar I also checked my console, and there are no errors, Sorry I missed to say that part

Comment: I mean, what is the response from call in network tab (if you are using chrome)

Comment: Just wondering why are you doing `redirect` in your controller

Comment: @secretsuperstar it's 404.

Comment: so, your endpoint is wrong in client side

Comment: @secretsuperstar I'm using the same code on another page. I just edited some of the code, It's working fine, But I don't know what's wrong with this one

Comment: tbh, it's not clear what you're doing. You give irrelevant code. You cannot access the link you create? why you create it then? create the one you can access, i.e. first find the working version that actually points to your endpoint. Your redirect points elsewhere that is not specified in your code.

Comment: @sarief if you read the previous comments. I said that I used the same code as the working one, I just edited the variables, naming etc. That's why I posted this, because I don't know what to do. If you could help me out then thanks :)

Comment: I've read it, but it does not make it clearer. You have too much unrelated code there. you should only provide url and endpoint. If you have analogue that's working - more so. Do remember that there is also config and other annotations that might affect the end result. And none of that is here

Comment: do you have `<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>` on top of your page (assuming you are using `jsp`)

Comment: @secretsuperstar I tried to place it, but the it still wont go to the controller

Comment: if it is still `404`, I would suggest try to get the right end point first. you can try to hit in browser and find it.

Comment: Here `$(nTd).html("<a class='linkColor' href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assignSpecificMessage?messageId="+messageId+"&sender_assign=" + encodeURIComponent(sender) + "&portId_assign="+portId+"&ticketNumber_assign=" + encodeURIComponent(oData.ticketNumber) + "'><span data-toggle='tooltip' title='Assign'><i class='ti-plus btn btn-simple btn-assign btn-icon' data-mode='assignMessageTicket'></i></span></a>");` you are using **`assignSpecificMessage`** but inside js, you are using **`assignMessageTicket`**. your question is too much conflicting.

Comment: **assignSpecificMessage** or **assignMessageTicket** which one is correct? or both are valid?

Comment: @secretsuperstar assignSpecific is the update one. try to check the last two codes I posted. They're the same. I even tried to experiment on the code further. I removed all the parameters even the preauthorize and it still wont go to the controller. I wonder why

Comment: it is not problem with authorisation or paramaters. since it is cause `404`, it means that the URL is wrong in your `js` script. can you try to hit the `url` in browser and see what happens.

Comment: does `http://localhost:8084/cwms/assignSpecificMessage?assign_sender=%2B639062165304&assign_portId=6&messageId=15416427366198288583&assign_ticketNumber=ADM-1809-00473` work? what is the output?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that href value for your link is getting build properly.

Go to browser elements tab and check the value for link href and make sure that it is not breaking.

[image]

or you can do that using jquery or javascript like below.

```
$("#idOfAnchorTag").on("click", function(){
   var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  ....

})
```

**UPDATE:** As you provided link in one of my comments, it is clear that your request parameters names are not matching with the controller one.

link :

```
http://localhost:8084/cwms/assignSpecificMessage?assign_sender=%2B639062165304&assign_portId=6&messageId=15416427366198288583&assign_ticketNumber=ADM-1809-00473
```

Controller :

```
@RequestParam(value = "sender_assign",required = true) String sender,
        @RequestParam(value = "portId_assign",required = true) String portId,@RequestParam(value = "messageId",required = true) String messageId,
        @RequestParam(value = "ticketNumber_assign",required = true) String ticketNumber,
```

You are using wrong parameter names in request so change all the parameters to controller one.

For example **`sender_assign` you are sending as `assign_sender` and so on.**

**SO to make it work use `sender_assign` instead of `assign_sender` and all other parameters also from client side(anchor href)**

Comment: It is not breaking, as I checked.

Comment: can you paste full <a> tag here

Comment: http://localhost:8084/cwms/assignSpecificMessage?assign_sender=%2B639062165304&assign_portId=6&messageId=15416427366198288583&assign_ticketNumber=ADM-1809-00473

Comment: @alien check it out

Comment: got the issue...in controller you are using sender_assign but in link href it is assign_sender same for all the parameters

Comment: @Alien `assign_sender` is `RequestParam`, does it cause `404`? I feel it should cause different error

Comment: @alien Update my question check it out

Comment: @alien I even tried to remove the PreAuthorize and the parameters. It still won't go to the controller